# Can't open website in ChromeDrive in Headless Mode

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I use Selenium and ChromeDriver for obtaining html-body of website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\ivan.nadin\Desktop\ProcurementCollector\procurement\procurement\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get('https://sevkab.nt-rt.ru/')
print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
```

ChromeDriver works in usual mode,but when I set up headless one,I get error message(it is this site that does not work,others are fine):

```
TimeoutException: Message: timeout
(Session info: headless chrome=73.0.3683.103)
(Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 
(47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 
x86_64)
```

Comment: Last time I was working with selenium and headless Chrome I noticed that headless Chrome is incredible slow. I couldnt figure out why so I just switched to not headless Chrome. Is there a particular reason why you are working with headless?

Comment: Thanks for answer.I need to use browser without GUI and tried also PhantomJS,but he didn't  work with this website too

Comment: Maybe this post on github may help you --> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6901

Comment: Thanks,but man from this post couldn't solve problem:(

Comment: I made an attempt to work with FirefoxHeadless and it was successful.Thanks for your responsiveness:)